# Getting out of bounds error using h2o.kmeans

Tags: r, out-of-memory, k-means, h2o

Trying to perform kmeans using h2o package. this is info about my h2o cluster:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: . Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         5 seconds 382 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.10.5.3 
    H2O cluster version age:    5 days  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_rgb505 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   14.22 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    4 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  4 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    R Version:                  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
```

My data is [32000, 14]. So, very small.
I get the following error when trying to perform a h2o.kmeans

```
h2o_kmeans <- h2o.kmeans(training_frame = spmx_train.h2o, 
                         nfolds = 10,
                         k = 20,
                         estimate_k = TRUE,
                         max_iterations = 10,
                         standardize = FALSE
)
```

Error:

> ```
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
>   at water.util.ArrayUtils.add(ArrayUtils.java:163)
>   at hex.ModelMetricsClustering$MetricBuilderClustering.reduce(ModelMetricsClustering.java:131)
>   at hex.ModelMetricsClustering$MetricBuilderClustering.reduce(ModelMetricsClustering.java:80)
>   at hex.ModelBuilder.cv_mainModelScores(ModelBuilder.java:512)
>   at hex.ModelBuilder.computeCrossValidation(ModelBuilder.java:292)
>   at hex.ModelBuilder$1.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:207)
>   at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1256)
>   at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
>   at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
>   at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
>   at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
>   at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
>
> Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
> ```

by when I change nfolds to 5, then it runs OK.
So, there is some sort of a memory problem.
it's just very hard to believe that h2o cannot handle 1o-folds kmeans on such a small data. 
Sometimes randomly it runs the code. I've closed all my other applications and only run R. Is there anything i can do to improve this?

Comment: I'm curious, what does `nfolds` supposed to do here?

Comment: What is the value of `Clustnum`? Have you tried setting it to a lower value just to check if it works (lets say Clustnum=2)?

Comment: Clustnum is 20 (I changed it in the code so it is clear) but the estimated cluster numbers are much fewer (7)
This code works when data is halved. but puzzled how it can't handle 32,000 rows, so trying to see if I can improve the memory management any way.

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira any chance you could send us a sample, failing, dataset so we can repro and check what's wrong? My guess would be a bug on our side. You can open a jira.h2o.ai ticket or ping us on our Gitter chat

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk .Sure i can send through a sample. Could you please give me instructions how to open a jira.h2oai ticket? it seems i can't access the public jira.h2oai to open a new issue.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Has this issue been solved? I met the same issue in 2019.